# Is this allowed in an `if statement`?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, environment-variables

```
# optional cropping
if [ "$1" == "cropit" ]; then
   ITS_CROP_TIME=
   mkdir cropped; for i in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -filter:v "crop=1920:980:0:-100" cropped/"${i%.*}.mp4"
   rm -r *.mp4
   cd cropped
   cp -r *.mp4 ../
fi
# optional cropping
```

Am I allowed to use `ITS_CROP_TIME=` string in this way (to capture the output of the code below)? And if I now go place this variable in my script somewhere, will the commands be executed at the variable definition?

What about this? Will this work?

```
if [ "$1" == "cropit" ]; then
   ITS_CROP_TIME=mkdir cropped; for i in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -filter:v "crop=1920:980:0:-100" cropped/"${i%.*}.mp4"; rm -r *.mp4; cd cropped; cp -r *.mp4 ../
fi
```

Comment: The statement `ITS_CROP_TIME=` assigns to `$ITS_CROP_TIME` an empty string.  It sounds vaguely like your goal, though, is to define a bash function.  If so, read about bash functions.

Comment: It's not empty, look at all the code below it. Thats what I am asking. Will those codes belong to that string?

Comment: What are you wanting to do with `ITS_CROP_TIME` ? I see you croppng videos, but what is `ITS_CROP_TIME` for?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
if [ "$1" == "cropit" ]; then
   ITS_CROP_TIME="$(
        mkdir cropped;
        for i in *.mp4; do 
           ffmpeg -i "$i" -filter:v "crop=1920:980:0:-100" cropped/"${i%.*}.mp4"
        done
        rm -r ./*.mp4
        cd cropped
        cp -r ./*.mp4 ../
    )"
fi
```

https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: This executes the commands immediately, and stores their output in `ITS_CROP_TIME`. My understanding of the question is that they want to store the commands in a variable for execution later, which is completely different. And not what variables are for at all; use a function instead of a variable.

Answer (score -2):

I'm assuming that you'd want to set the variable `ITS_CROP_TIME` to a collection of commands for running later?

That's what functions are for:

```bsh
crop_all_in_dir () {
    local source_dir="$1"
    local dest_dir="$2"

    mkdir -p "$dest_dir"

    for file in "$source_dir"/*.mp4; do
        [ ! -f "$file" ] && continue
        ffmpeg -i "$file" -filter:v "crop=1920:980:0:-100" "$dest_dir/(basename "${file%.*}").mp4"
    done
}
```

Then you may want to call this later in the script as

```bsh
# optional cropping
if [ "$1" = "cropit" ]; then
    crop_all_in_dir . cropped
fi
```

i.e., crop all the `*.mp4` files in the current directory and place the cropped files in the `cropped` directory (a subdirectory of the current directory), creating the output directory if it does not already exist.

The function does the cropping non-destructively, so any replacing of the original files (your `cp` etc.) would be done from outside of that function.

Comment: That cool, and thank you... but I am trying to run this within a bigger script, not by itself. That would require extra steps. That's why the notes say `# optional cropping`

Comment: I am too much of a noob still, sorry. I am trying really hard though.

Comment: @Anonymous The function would be part of the bigger script.